# fetching data from database with dropdown selection without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

My dropdown list contains options like monthly plan, yearly plan, etc... when I select a value from the dropdown list, I want to fetch data like no of days from database.. Then I want to select the validity starting date. When I click the starting date, based on the no of days that is already fetched from the database and increment that value to the starting date and show expiry date. How can I solve it in codeigniter. Anyone please help me.

Comment: That's a typical task for using ajax.

Comment: I am new in this...will u please help me???

Comment: At first write some code and show it here. Write your view with the dropdown list and the model/controller which handles the task coming from the dropdown list. Then come back here and we build the ajax task.

Comment: You should at least display the dropdown list html, and the way you store these plans in your database.